# I am studying for the Toefl test, I found this sentence in one book, it looks strange to me, is it right?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is this sentence right

> Its original justifications outmoded, **its operations inscrutable**, and its effects at odds with the goals of a democracy, the Electoral College is an institution that some would like to abandon.

from Kaplan Toefl prep.? Why the book did not say

> Its original justifications are outmoded, **its operations are inscrutable**..."

I don't know the reason, is it a typing error? Or is it still grammatically correct?

Answer (score 3):

These are examples of non-finite clauses They are quite common in [participial phrases](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm), but are unusual with a normal adjective.

Here is an example with an active participle (-ing):

> The horses sweating, they climbed the hill.

and with a passive (past) participle (-ed).

> The horses stabled, he went inside to get something to eat.

You can also do it with a prepositional phrase:

> The kids in bed, they settled down in front of the television

Doing it with a non-participial adjective is unusual, though:

> The horses ready, they started to climb the hill

**outmoded** is a past participle, so this is quite conventional: maybe this sets the tone for the structure of the second clause where **inscrutable** is a non-participle adjective. **at odds with the goals of a democracy** is a  prepositional phrases.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly correct in terms of grammar although it is an awkward sentence to read. It strikes me as rather old-fashioned oratory. Perhaps it came from a speech. Each of the clauses beginning with 'its' is adjectival and qualifies 'the Electoral College'. A simpler example is 'Its brakes squealing, the car stopped just in time.'

Comment: outmoded qualifies "the Electoral College's original justifications", et cetera.